# Asp Net core web API. EF Core не отслеживает изменения Entity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Использую net core 3.1 + Entity framework core. Есть модель User и UserType, которую сохраняю в БД. К ним использую отдельные DTO для создания и чтения.
В контроллер приходит Dto, маплю ее в модель юзер. Далее модель отправляю в бд, сохраняю. Потом в контроллере обратно маплю в Dto, и там Ид и юзер тип не обновленные, хотя все в базу сохранено. Отслеживание не отключал.
Проблему в контроллере решил созданием новым экземпляров модели, но это неверно.

Как решить вопрос?

Модельки:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int UserTypeId { get; set; } 

    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }
} 

public class UserType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

К ним DTO для создания

```
public class UserCreateDto
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nickname not specified")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password not specified")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords don't match")]
    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }
}

public class UserTypeCreateDto
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "User's type not specified")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

и для чтения

```
public class UserReadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public UserTypeReadDto UserType { get; set; }
}

public class UserTypeReadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Реализация метода в репозитории юзера. Уже тут пришлось возвращать обновленный юзер. Иначе в контроллере после вызова этого метода данные не обновлялись. Отслеживание для EF Core не отключал, метод AsNoTracking() не вызываю.

```
public async Task<User> AddAsync(User user)
{
    var context = dbContextFactory.Create(typeof(UserRepository));

    var userTypeId = await context.UserTypes
                                  .Where(x => x.Name == "Client")
                                  .Select(x => x.Id)
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (userTypeId == 0)
    {
        UserType userType = new UserType
        {
            Name = "Client"
        };

        await context.UserTypes.AddAsync(userType);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
 
        userTypeId = userType.Id;
    }

    User newUser = new User
    {
        Nickname = user.Nickname,
        Email = user.Email,
        PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        Password = user.Password,
        UserTypeId = userTypeId
    };

    await context.Users.AddAsync(newUser);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return newUser;
}
```

И собственно контроллер.

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync(UserCreateDto userDto)
{
    if (userDto == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var user = mapper.Map<User>(userDto);

    //after saving to the database(context.SaveChangesAsync()), the user model is not updated.
    //I was unable to fix this.So I do the following:
    
    var userResult = await userRepository.AddAsync(user); // get user with Id from database.

    userResult = await userRepository.GetByIdAsync(userResult.Id); // get user with userType from 
    database.

    var userReadDto = mapper.Map<UserReadDto>(userResult);

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUserByIdAsync), new { id = userReadDto.Id }, userReadDto);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Добавьте в код комментарии, до какого места всё идёт нормально, а где ломается.

Comment: Зачем вызывается `GetByIdAsync`? Ведь `userResult` ещё до этого получен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подсказали то, что лежало на поверхности. Я в репозитории создавал новый экземпляр юзера вместо обновления существующего. В этом была вся проблема.